# C# DataGridView Check if empty

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview which gets filled with data returned from a linq query.
If the query returns no results I want to display a messagebox.
Is there a way of checking to see if the datagridview is empty?

Regards

Comment: Is this ASP .Net or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can find out if it is empty by checking the number of rows in the DataGridView. If  `myDataGridView.Rows.Count == 0` then your DataGridView is empty.

Comment: This doesn't always work as stated in the answer below by Ashraf Abusada

Answer (score 3):

The `DGV.Rows.Count` method of checking if DGV is empty does not work if the option `AllowUserToAddRows` is set to true.

You have to disable `AllowUserToAddRows = false` then check for empty like this:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows != null && dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Linq results, you can hide the datagridview and show some other control (like a Literal or something) that shows the message.  If you want some sort of messagebox popup, you'd need to throw some JavaScript in there.

Comment: can't see why jscript would be needed at all, ever

Answer (score 1):

A lot of answers here have a reference to `Rows.Count`. Normally, that does not pose a problem and it would in most cases be an overkill to do what I am about to suggest.

But for reasons mentioned in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it may not be a good idea to call `Rows.Count` if the `DataGridView` frequently has a lot of data (`>~ 5000` cells in the memory profiling I did to validate that article a while back).

> Avoid using the `Count` property of the
>   `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection` to determine
>   the number of selected cells. Instead, use the
>   `DataGridView.GetCellCount` method and pass in the
>   `DataGridViewElementStates.Selected` value. Similarly, use the
>   `DataGridViewRowCollection.GetRowCount` and
>   `DataGridViewColumnCollection.GetColumnCount` methods to determine the
>   number of selected elements, rather than accessing the selected row
>   and column collections.

In such cases you can use

```
myDataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(.) == 0
```

If you are not dealing with fast changing data or a huge amount of data (or worse, huge amount of fast changing data) then simply use Rows.Count --it does not hurt that much.

Answer (score 1):

//this gives rows count=1

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0 && dataGridView1.Rows != null)
```

//so finally I modifieded code as below and it works for me

```
if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count>1 && dataGridView1.Rows != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Rows.Count property of the datagridview.

Although you might also want to look into the EmptyDataText property of the DataGridView. It might save you showing a messagebox.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
dataGridView1.RowCount == 0
```