# Checking if DataGridView is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to check if my `DataGridView` is empty. Of course I searched on internet and they are saying you have to do it like this:

```
if (datagridview.Rows.Count < 0) {
 //my messagebox
}
```

But when I have a empty table and say :

```
int test = datagridview.Rows.Count;
MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
```

The `MessageBox` is telling me `1` ??

How is that possible, now I can't check if a table is empty?

Comment: you can go to this link to see: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972496/c-sharp-datagridview-check-if-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting [`AllowUserToAddRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) to `False` can fixes your problem:

```
dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Then:

```
int test = datagridview.Rows.Count;
MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());//Return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if datagridview is empty; Simply use,

`if (dataGridView1.RowCount == 0)
    {
       //your msg here
    }`